# Issues accessing the (forge-environment) from OSX command line

Tags: macos, command-line, trigger.io, forge

I'm following the [Trigger.io Forge tutorials](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-the-command-line-tools) and I can't get to work properly from the command line on OSX 10.8.

Using the terminal and the Forge tutorials, I go to the forge-workspace folder  and type this into the terminal:

```
$HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge create
```

and get this back:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:forge-workspace mattm$ $HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge create
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.17
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools

This name is what your application will be called on devices. You can change it later     through config.json.
App Name: Weather App
[   INFO] Registering new app "Weather App" with trigger.io...
[   INFO] Fetching initial project template
[   INFO] Building app for the first time...
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[   INFO] App structure created. To proceed:
[   INFO] 1) Put your code in the "src" folder
[   INFO] 2) Run forge build to make a build
[   INFO] 3) Run forge run to test out your build
Matts-MacBook-Pro:forge-workspace mattm$
```

The tutorial says:

> At this point, you should have a command terminal open that looks something like:
>
> ```
> (forge-environment)
> ```

But this doesn't show up. Plus, when I look in my library directory(and do a systemwide search), I don't see any folders labeled Trigger.

And when I try to follow the tutorial directions and do stuff like use the forge create command, nothing happens:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:hello-world mattm$ forge create</p>
-bash: forge: command not found

Matts-MacBook-Pro:hello-world mattm$ $forge create</p>
-bash: create: command not found
```

Before you ask, yes I installed Python and am able to build and run the app using the Forge browser interface.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

On Mac OS X, add the following to your bash profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Comment: why the down vote?  I have run this on multiple machines now with no problem

Answer (score 2):

I've pushed an update to the Getting Started docs to clarify this:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-the-command-line-tools

There is no longer a need to look out for the "(forge-environment)". If you add the path to the forge executable to your PATH then you'll be able to run the commands as you have tried.